# How can a web service, or even a client, be generated automatically from an open-api spec?

Tags: python, yaml, client, openapi

This is going to be a little more theoretical of a question than my usual ones are. I don't really want to get into specifics because its an area in which I know so little I don't even know how to ask anything specific.

Recently, I had a coworker with SUBSTANTIALLY more experience than me take a look at a client library I wrote. It was my first python client library (or rather, my first library at all) I've ever written. It was pretty simple. My work has 5 webservices. Rather than having to know the specific implementation of these webservices, my boss wanted developers to be able to simply use the client.

So I wrote a very simple wrapper around the webservices that make it much easier to call them. Also, rather than returning simple dictionaries, I created a bunch of data classes to mimic the real world data we use and the client returns these instead.

I kinda got dressed down by this coworker. They didn't attack me personally, they know how new I am (less than 6 months total experience) meanwhile this guy did system architecture engineering stuff at Philips for like 10 years. Rather was peeved at my boss that I was even allowed to write this stuff manually.

He was able to generate a client directly from our open api spec yaml document. He says doing this is better because if we generate both our web service and our client for that webservice from the same yaml document, they'll always be matching each other.

I don't disagree with the concept, but I can't even begin to imagine how this is possible. An open api spec doesn't include any of the logic for our webservice. It includes the paths (endpoints) and includes the kind of data each end point takes in, and the kind of data the endpoint spits out. But no logic.

How is it possible even to take an open api spec and generate a client from it? And if THAT's possible, even more baffling to me is how you'd generate an actual webservice from it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have no idea what an "open api spec" is, but I would imagine that whatever your coworker generated, it was just scaffolding.  It defined all the required url paths and such, but didn't contain any actual business logic.

Comment: Sorry, I thought open api was a pretty well know specification. To make it easier to share webservices, there's a popular specification api's can follow. I believe the spec is up to 3.0 right now. Smart-api (formerly swagger) would accept open-api-spec compliant yaml files and would both generate some documentation to view on their website, but also the specification (apparently) can be used to generate webservices and clients. So i'm told. Yeah I had ASSUMED it was a scaffolding, which is why I didn't use it. he made it sound like the week of work I did could have been done in an hour. thanks

Comment: _which is why I didn't use it_ It's still worth using as a starting point.  Fill in your business logic as appropriate.

Comment: I used one as a reference mostly for the setup.py since I'd never made a package before. most of that info was correct in setup.py that was generated